# count the value is display on apache-tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, apache, tomcat, soap

i have try to develop count the value is displayed on my apache-tomcat console window.
here am using following code:

```
public class RetailerWs {
 public int data(){
int count=0;

count++;

try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pro","root","");

    PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("select * from orders where status='Q' AND date=CURDATE()");
     ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();


}

      catch(Exception exc){
      System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
      }


    return count;
       }

        }
```

my another class is:

```
  public class Demo {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    RetailerWs obj = new RetailerWs();
    System.out.println(obj.data());
   }

  }
```

In my database have 2 values are matched above query.but the output is displayed is always 1.why dis error is occurred here.please help me what loop condition is am used here.give me some solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't actually looking at the results of your query. `count` is 1 because of the `count++` earlier in the code.

You need something like:

```
while(result.next()) {
    // Do something with the row returned.
    // e.g. count += result.getInt[1]; if the first col is a count.
}
```

Comment: i got the output.because my date field is saved in DATE(yyyy-mm-dd) format.but now my database have date filed.it is saved in timestamp(int) format.now how is develop this.please help me

Comment: You should start another question for this, but Date.getTime() is where you need to start looking.

Answer (score 0):

add this lines after execute a query.

```
count = 0;
while ( result.next() ) 
count++;
```